# Presenting a UIViewController from an SKscene (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, interface-builder, sprite-kit

There are several posts on the internet asking how to correctly combine SpriteKit and Storyboard/Interface builder. In particular nobody is able to move from an SKscene to a desired UIViewController. NONE of the solutions on the net really address this problem! Is it really not possible to do this?? If so, it would be a significant limitation of SpriteKit...

Comment: All the answers I have given have answered this.

Comment: Actually I believe there's no tutorial on it because it's not even a special case scenario once you know how Storyboard transitions (segues) work. The problem stems from SK users expecting to transition from a scene when they fail to consider that the scene won't transition, it's the view. So just send a message from the scene to the view or view controller and that's it. The main problem then can be distilled as "how do I send a message from the scene to the view (controller)?" and there are answers for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move directly from an `SKScene` to another `UIViewController`.

However, the `SKScene` is already **contained** in a `UIViewController`.

You can use `delegation` to pass a method call from the scene to its controller. The controller can then move to another view controller.

So...

1. Create a delegate protocol that contains a method something like... `- (void)transitionToOtherViewController;`
2. Set the current view controller as the delegate of your scene.

   `self.scene.delegate = self;`
3. When you want to move to another view controller. In the scene you would have something like...

   `[self.delegate transitionToOtherViewController];`

Then in the view controller you have...

```
- (void)transitionToOtherViewController
{
    MyOtherViewController *controller = [MyOtherViewController new];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Or something like this...