# Trouble with SKScenes and Segueing to ViewControllers SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

In my GameViewController i have two scenes, one being the GameScene and another being a scene (EndScene) that is switched to when the player dies. In the first block of code below is my EndScene Scene that is supposed to switch to my main menu viewcontroller, however it wont for some reason. I'm not getting any errors or likewise, it just stays on EndScene. In the second block of code is my GameViewController.swift file. Can someone help point out what im doing wrong here and what i can do to fix it?

EndScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class EndScene : SKScene {
    var viewController : UIViewController?
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.segue()

    }
    func segue() {
        self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameToMain", sender: viewController)
    }
}
```

GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.viewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene) 

        }
        if let scene = EndScene(fileNamed: "EndScene"){
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve
            rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.viewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting a UIViewController from an SKscene (SpriteKit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930592/presenting-a-uiviewcontroller-from-an-skscene-spritekit)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let newScene: GameScene = GameScene(size: size)
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5)
view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
```

There is other transitions you can use, but try this code and see if it will switch your scenes

Comment: the transition form scene to scene is all good, its just the transition from the EndScene to viewController thats not working

Comment: the UIViewController is a wrapper for your scenes. you can't leave a scene and go to the ViewController. you can however access the ViewController and it's functions.

Comment: in your game you should be transitioning between scenes. The same GameViewController presents both scenes. So a typical scenario might be... start on a MenuScene -> transition to GameScene. Play Game. transition from GameScene -> to EndScene. display scores. transition from EndScene -> to MenuScene (if game over) or transition from EndScene -> to GameScene (if play again option)

Comment: yes but my main menu is not a scene its a view controller, so how do i get to that from my scene?

Comment: why would your main menu be in the ViewController? is it written in UIKit? You should just create a scene file called MenuScene and then transition to it.

Comment: yes it is written in UIKit and in a view controller